# Django - How to get details from many-to-many relationship in multiple select form field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, many-to-many, checkboxlist

I have 2 models linked with a M2M relationship and I would like to build a form allowing to manage the links but also to add controls on selected values.
This take place outside admin templates.

I managed defining the form to manage links but I was not able to consider additional information to define validity controls.

Here are my models:

```py
class EventGroup(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="société"
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(UserComp, verbose_name="utilisateurs", blank=True)
    group_name = models.CharField("nom", max_length=100)
    weight = models.IntegerField("poids", default=0)

class Event(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="société"
    )
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(EventGroup, verbose_name="groupes", blank=True)
    rules = [("MAJ", "Majorité"), ("PROP", "Proportionnelle")]
    event_name = models.CharField("nom", max_length=200)
    event_date = models.DateField("date de l'événement")
    slug = models.SlugField()
    current = models.BooleanField("en cours", default=False)
    quorum = models.IntegerField(default=33)
    rule = models.CharField(
        "mode de scrutin", max_length=5, choices=rules, default="MAJ"
    )
```

The form:

```py
class EventDetail(forms.ModelForm):
    groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label = "Liste des groupes",
        queryset = EventGroup.objects.none(),
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required = False
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['event_name', 'event_date', 'quorum', 'rule', 'groups']
```

The view:

```py
def event_detail(request, evt_id=0):
    if evt_id > 0:
        current_event = Event.objects.get(id=evt_id)
        event_form = EventDetail(request.POST or None, instance=current_event)
    else:
        event_form = EventDetail(request.POST or None)

    company = Company.get_company(request.session['comp_slug'])
    event_form.fields['groups'].queryset = EventGroup.objects.\
                                                        filter(company=company).\
                                                        order_by('group_name')
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if event_form.is_valid():
            event_form.save()

    return render(request, "polls/event_detail.html", locals())
```

This works with no problem to add or remove groups dedicated to the selected or new event, but what I need is to add group's weight information and control that total weight of selected groups is exactly 100. On top of that, I will also need to ensure that each user in the selected groups are listed only once.
Does anybody have any clue on how to implement these controls, or at least how to display additional information to provide the user with related necessary information?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to display group weight inside the options would be to change the `__str__` method of EventGroup. It would look something like this:

```
class EventGroup(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
    Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="société"
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(UserComp, verbose_name="utilisateurs", blank=True)
    group_name = models.CharField("nom", max_length=100)
    weight = models.IntegerField("poids", default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.group_name} ({self.weight})"
```

So a group called 'Group' with weight 75 would appear on the options list as "Group (75)"

If you want to dynamically display total weight of selected options, some javascript will be needed. You'll need a function that's triggered when any option is clicked and somehow finds the weight for that option. Following the `__str__` solution, it could look like this:

```
var current_weight = 0

document.querySelector('#id_groups').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
    option = e.target
    weight = option.textContent.split('(')
    weight = parseInt(weight[-1][:-1])

    if (option.checked) {
      current_weight -= weight
    } else {
      current_weight += weight
    }
    document.getElementById('current_weight').textContent = current_weight
    submit_button = document.getElementById('submit')
    if (current_weight == 100) {
      submit_button.disabled = false
    } else {
      submit_button.disabled = true
  }
})
```

This will have to be inside a .js file that's imported by your polls/event_detail.html template.

What this script does is listen to clicks on any of the LI elements of django CheckboxMultiple widget and get its weight via some simple string manipulation. The string will be something like "Name of the group (23)". If the option is checked, the script will subtract its weight from current_weight (the user has de-selected the option). Otherwise, it will add the weight. The updated sum will be displayed dinamically on an element you'll add to the event_detail.html template with id='current_weight'. This variable can then control whether the form can be submitted or not, by enabling or disabling its submit button.

If you want server-side validation of this weight == 100 limit, you could do something like that in views.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
total_weight = 0
try:
    post = request.POST

    for item in post['groups']:
        weight = EventGroup.objects.get(pk=item).weight
        total_weight += weight
except:
    pass

if event_form.is_valid() and total_weight == 100:
    event_form.save()
```

This way instance will be saved only if weight == 100. You can pass an appropriate error message to the user otherwise.

I wasn't able to test this script properly, but I hope the idea helps. I'm not sure what you mean by "ensure that each user in the selected groups are listed only once", so I couldn't answer. Bonne chance!

Comment: Many thanks @YuriAFGomes for your reply.
Well, once the information of weight comes, I actually also intended to define a js script.
The point is that I hoped there was a way to have the information directly but this workaround is quite suitable.
Thanks again

Comment: For the latest point, what I men is that the Groups you see in Models are groups of users; for each event, users should appear only once (or not at all) which means that if several groups are linked to the event, each user  is not supposed to belong to more than one group.
I presume the best solution is to make this test on the server side